# Stunnel a web service client configuration error

Tags: stunnel

In Stunnel,I have this configuration:

```
[ws]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:80
connect = webservice.it:443
```

I make a http request to 127.0.0.1:80 and I want that stunnel redirect to webservice.it:443.

But it doesn't work.

In the log I have this error:

```
LOG6[]: Peer certificate not required
LOG7[]: TLS state (connect): before SSL initialization
LOG7[]: TLS state (connect): SSLv3/TLS write client hello
LOG3[]: SSL_connect: Peer suddenly disconnected
LOG5[]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to TLS, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
LOG7[]: Deallocating application specific data for session connect address
```

How can I do? Thanks a lot

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve? When you start stunnel with `client = yes`, it's supposed to connect to an stunnel server so that an encrypted tunnel is created between you and a server you want to connect.

Comment: I use stunnel in the server of my client, which send the HTTP request to the web service. Unfortunally, my software client doesn't support the HTTPS request so I have to use stunnel to redirect to the web service

Comment: So is it an stunnel server that is listening to (tcp) port 443 on webservice.it? If so, how is it configured?

Comment: no, in webservice there isn't a stunnel server

Comment: So what is even listening on that port? An https server? I'm not sure if stunnel is even what you want.

Comment: Unfortunally, I don't know nothing about the web service. I have to connect with it, but with my client I can't. My client support only HTTP request. Is there a way to create a HTTPS request using stunnel?